# React Native: Using Firebase Crashlytics and Bugsnag

Tags: react-native, crashlytics, bugsnag

We use Bugsnag for general error catching, and we use firebase for a host of other features.

At the moment crashes and error only got to Bugsnag (react-native-bugsnag), but we'd like them to also go to Crashlytics (which is installed as part of React Native Firebase).

Is this possible? If so how.

Answer (score 1):

While Bugsnag and Crashlytics can usually operate fine alongside each other, there are some cases where other error reporting tools can cause interference and thus the error may only land in one or the other.

I'd recommend trying Bugsnag and Crashlytics out separately to confirm the behaviour in case something else is causing the issue, or swapping the order in which they are initialized as that will likely make a difference.

Please feel free to reach out to us at Bugsnag support to discuss your config in more detail.